# Binding existing Kendo grid to a new JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have following `kendoGrid` on my page that on load receives `JSON` object from the specified URL.

But later i want to bind it to some other `JSON` data received from other source. Is there a way a can bind-refresh existing data containing grid with a new `JSON` object?

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    sortable: true,
    groupable: true,
    scrollable: true,

    pageable: {
        pageSizes: 9
    },
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../Get/JsonData",
                dataType: "Json"
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "name", title: "Name", width: 100 },
        ... ...
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could either replace all the data in the DataSource with:

```
var newData = [ "some", "data", "array" ];

var gridWidget = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
gridWidget.dataSource.data(newData);
```

Or you can give the grid a whole new DataSource (I recommend this approach):

```
var newData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [ "some", "data", "array" ]
});

var gridWidget = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
gridWidget.setDataSource(newData);
```

and of course `newData` in my example would just be whatever data is returned from your function.

Comment: it says in the console: `[] has no method 'fetch' ` where [] is the JSON in newData

Comment: Using which approach? Calling `dataSource.data()` or `grid.setDataSource()`? My guess is you are passing an array where you should be passing a `DataSource`

Comment: using `grid.setDataSource()` i am passing a `JSON` object which in your case is the `data` object, i tried just giving my object where you have initialised the `data` object but didnt work. How can i convert a `JSON` object which i get from server `theObject` into DataSource?

Comment: `var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: JSON.parse(someJsonString) });`

Answer (score 0):

Is the structure of the new JSON the same (same columns and same data model)? If so then yes, just play with `transport.read` or `transport.read.url` and instead of defining it as a `string` define it as a function that returns either one or the other.

Remember that [`transport.read`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read) might be an object or a function. Same happens for [`transport.read.url`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.url)

Comment: at the page load i want it to load from the `url` but after a function is called i want it to replace the existing data with the new `JSON` data returned by the function.

Comment: So use the url for the initial load and then use `grid.dataSource.data(newJSON);` for replacing it.

Comment: after fethcing data it gives me this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: oSId is not defined`, `oSID` is a column i have used in the for a command button `{ command: { text: "Options", click: showHideOptions }, title: " ", width: "90px", attributes: { "id": "#: oSID#", } }`